# how to automatically turn the picture in the right form (library cropper )?

Tags: android

I use library cropper [here](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/wiki#Contributions) in my project.
Everything works cool, but if a photo was made in portrait mode, it flips and is displayed in landscape mode.

Here is an original photo - [original](http://joxi.ru/MAjRaQ5SKZq7Ae) 
This is opened by the program - [program](http://joxi.ru/Q2KjolZfJX8Ymj)

There is a method in the library `cropImageView.rotateImage(90);` I can add a button that rererses the picture when pressed. But what can I do to make it run once loaded in the right mode?

```
imageCrop = (CropImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageCrop);
        String picturePath = getArguments().getString("image");
        crudeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        imageCrop.setImageBitmap(crudeImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the original image into bitmap in its orientation. Detect image orientation using [`ExifInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), then use [`Matrix`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to rotate your bitmap to image's original orientation:

```
crudeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
float rotationDegrees = getRotationDegreesToOriginal(picturePath);
if (rotationDegrees != 0f) {
    crudeImage = rotateImage(crudeImage, rotationDegrees);
}

/**
 * Rotate a bitmap by given degrees
 * @param bitmap    original bitmap
 * @param degrees   rotation degrees
 * @return  rotated bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bitmap, float degrees) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degrees);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

/**
 * Get rotation degrees that need to be applied to rotate an image to its original orientation
 * @param fileName  full path to image
 * @return  rotation degrees, or 0 if file not found
 */
public static float getRotationDegreesToOriginal(String fileName) {
    final ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return 0f;
    }

    // Detect original orientation to rotate back to
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return 180f;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return 90f;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return 270f;
        default:
            return 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: great! even I did not have to change anything, other than the code! thank you!